# Breaking thumbs

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

After a humanoid enemy falls unconscious to negative hp in combat, can I break their thumbs?

I want them alive but unable to physically hurt then after the fact.

How would I go about just snapping their thumbs until they are unusable?

This is inspired by my halfling rogue who didn't want tie the bad guy up but still wanted him know he still meant business.

Comment: Are you asking if there are rules for breaking thumbs in Pathfinder? Or are you asking how we would rule this/have ruled this in the past?

Comment: Either question I suppose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules of the game don't go in such detail, the simulation provided is not so granular.

While true that ample detail and fine granularity are provided for many little things in the game, the game does so for the most probable combat (and non-combat) actions, and leaves the rest to the DM to decide.

Ultimately, Pathfinder is a roleplaying game, and as such it is supposed to be a game where you can have your character do whatever you imagine he can do, and mutilating someone so that it cannot hold a weapon anymore is at least imagined by the authors, who wrote spells such as *regeneration* exactly to heal the kind of damage that the rules never tell you how to apply.

Talk with your DM to define the details. It is surely a possible outcome, it just isn't pre-defined anywhere (that I know of - it's hard to prove a negative).

Answer (score 5):

Use (appropriately and carefully) the **Arm** section of [the Called Shot optional rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/variants/calledShots.html) detailed on Paizo's official website, if you're the DM. Show those rules to your DM if you're a player, talk it over whether the rules are OK for yor team and game.

> Debilitating Blow: A debilitating blow deals 1d6 points of Dexterity
>   damage and 1d6 points of Strength damage. The blow renders the arm
>   useless until healed unless the target succeeds at a Fortitude saving
>   throw. If the saving throw fails by 5 or more, the arm is severed or
>   otherwise mangled such that only regeneration or similar effects can
>   repair it. The target also suffers the effects of a called shot to the
>   arm (if the arm remains usable) for 2d6 minutes.

Comment: Would the enemy still get the fort save if they are unconscious?

Comment: In my subjective opinion / ruling yes, they would. Their body's resistance in this case does not depend on their being conscious.

Comment: If that's the case could I keep trying again until it breaks? Would they keep losing STR and DEX?

Comment: This is getting very subjective here, but I'd allow repeated tries, yes, but wouldn't have the subject lose further STR and DEX, as you're not targeting the whole arm (as described in the rules) but only a small portion of the hand. (I don't see how this would be less... evil than tying someone up without causing semi-permanent damage, mind you.)

Comment: It would totally be more evil, but what if I didn't have a rope at the time?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  In fact, in the Second Darkness Adventure Path there's a pirate ship (the *Teeth of Araska*) that has a Chelish captain with his thumbs cut off in its brig, which even makes it canonical.

My pirate PCs thought that was a snazzy idea and tends to have someone with cut-off thumbs in the brig now that they killed the previous crew and took the ship. If their victim is helpless, there's really no rule needed, off go the thumbs. Someone badass enough might still try to kick or head-butt or dive overboard if they get a chance, but weapon wielding is basically right out.